# Mysql select random rows from a complex result

Tags: mysql

I have a select similar like this one:

```
SELECT TABLE_4.ID, TABLE_4.USERNAME, TABLE_4.PHOTO,

SELECT(COUNT(SOMETHING) FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ..) AS NUM_ALL
SELECT(COUNT(SOMETHING) FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ..) AS NUM_DONE
SELECT(COUNT(SOMETHING) FROM TABLE_2 WHERE ..) AS NUM_LIKES

SELECT(COUNT(SOMETHING) FROM TABLE_3 WHERE ..) AS FOLLOWING
SELECT(COUNT(SOMETHING) FROM TABLE_3 WHERE ..) AS FOLLOWERS

CASE WHEN...

FROM TABLE_4
LEFT JOIN...
LEFT JOIN...
LEFT JOIN...

WHERE <condition>

GROUP BY TABLE_4.ID LIMIT 1000;
```

Say there are 5000 results of this query. I would like to have the first 1000 in random order. I think rand() is out of the question for this complex and long query.

Can you lend me a hand here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use RAND. Just add

```
... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000;
```

at the end of your Query. No matter how compley the query is, RAND() will be applied when the final results are fectched (the first line of an `EXPLAIN` result).